# XSLT 1.0 for-each 'starts-with' (with variable length)

Tags: xslt-1.0, startswith

thinking aloud, re approach(es )

- Input collection (xml) records being transformed eg for-each Order.
- With an xml 'exclude' (reference-collection) param, to filter out records,
  eg only transform (for-each Order) **where**
  (**start** of) current order/reference is **not** equal to **any** Reference in the References collection.

For simplicity, Order input example

```
<Orders>
 <Order number="1"> <!-- Include -->
  <Reference>AB123</Reference>
 </Order>
 <Order number="2"> <!-- Exclude -->
  <Reference>C3PO</Reference>
 </Order>
</Orders>
```

and the exclude references (of variable length)

```
<References>
 <Reference>ABC</Reference>
 <Reference>BC</Reference>
 <Reference>AC</Reference>
 <Reference>Z7</Reference>
</References>
```

- I think there's probably several ways to do this, but maybe one / two that are recommended, for performance...
- thinking about variables (don't think a key will help), not sure if a for-each in a for-each is an option, or how that would work
- the rub (I think) is a starts-with() approach, where the numberofcharacters to compare varies... so maybe some c# may be *best* (from a performance perspective)

assume 1000 orders, 200 references... if that impacts decisions on approach, in XSLT 1.0

Any recommended/preferred|optimised approach?

many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you have too many choices here. You need to loop over the references, removing the orders that start with the current reference at each iteration.Then output the remaining orders. (And by "loop" I mean a recursive template, not `xsl:for each`.)

Comment: thanks for the update. re 'recursive' I was looking at (and maybe misunderstanding) options & opportunities to compare with

- <reference> in $variable (for performance)
- options to do some (nodeset | ) clever / voodoo 
- using a position() counter or similar

one quick, related question, re the required (recommended) recursive approach...

Would you have to manually increment, to go through the collection?

(Just wondering if examples like ones I'm seeing, with-param name="pI" select="$pI+1" ... is THE way you're referring to ... apologies if I've misunderstood or am unclear

Comment: Incrementing a counter is just one way to loop over a node-set - and not necessarily the best one. I have posted an answer that shows how I would approach this. Do note that the result in your example is NOT what you indicate: I see no reason to exclude "C3PO". -- Re performance: it can vary from one processor to another. Still, very often an elegant solution is also a performant one. And with only 1000 orders and 200 references I don't think you need to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point to understand here, IMHO, is that the `starts-with()` function takes two *strings* as it arguments - not *node-sets*. This means that while it's very easy to select **all** orders that do not start with a specific string, using:

```
Order[not(starts-with(Reference, $string)]
```

it is not so easy* to reverse the point-of-view and ask "does this `Order` start with **any one** of the given strings?".

This then determines the strategy to take here, which I have already outlined in the comment to your question: loop over the reference strings, removing the orders that start with the current reference string at each iteration. Then output the remaining orders.

The other important point to remember here is that **`xsl:for-each` is not a loop**. It does not allow for an exit condition and - much more importantly for our case - it does not allow passing the result of one iteration to the next. Since we want to "dwindle" the node-set of orders at each iteration, we must a use a truly recursive tool:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-references">References.xml</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/Orders">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="exclude-orders">
            <xsl:with-param name="orders" select="Order"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="references" select="document($path-to-references)/References/Reference"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="exclude-orders">
    <xsl:param name="orders"/>
    <xsl:param name="references"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$references">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="exclude-orders">
                <xsl:with-param name="orders" select="$orders[not(starts-with(Reference, $references[1]))]" />
                <xsl:with-param name="references" select="$references[position() > 1]" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$orders"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

(*) On second thought, you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-references">References.xml</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/Orders">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="Order">
            <xsl:if test="not(document($path-to-references)/References/Reference[starts-with(current()/Reference, .)])">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's a rather awkward code, but it is short and it works.